# which h2o components/functionalities are free

Tags: h2o

I would like to test drive H2O run from R. I can install it locally using install.packages no problem. There are several options to scale H2O up. For example, [H2O4GPU](https://www.h2o.ai/products/h2o4gpu/) and [H2O Sparkling Water](https://www.h2o.ai/products/h2o-sparkling-water/). For security reasons, we would like to use these options on premise. If we pay for the hardware, would H2O still be free or do certain components/functionalities cost money? Sorry, this may be obvious to you but personally I am a bit overwhelmed by the possibilities at this point in time. Any clarification, would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

H2O-3, Sparkling Water and H2O4GPU are all open-source (also this is software, H2O.ai doesn't provide hardware for these).

Driverless AI is a closed source product.

If you go to the [company page](https://www.h2o.ai/download/#h2o) and click on Products you will see that the open source products are listed separate from the closed-source products.

Comment: To clarify, Sparking Water is just a Spark package that allows you to use the regular H2O-3 code yet H2O4GPU is a completely different codebase so it's not really a "scaling up" of H2O-3.